# What precautions should I take when using '0' in PHP as a number?

Tags: php

In PHP `0` is treated as boolean false. Hence, whenever I'm in a situation where a function has to return a numerical value and I have it return 0, or when I have a MySQL `bool` column with possible values of `0/1`, and I use code such as this:

```
$active=(isActive()) ? 1 : 0;
$this->db->set('isActive',$active);
```

I get a feeling in the back of my mind that the `0` might be converted to `null` or an empty string e.g `""`.

What precautions do I need to take in order to have `0` always treated as an integar and not anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few places where `0` and `'0'` are treated a little bit specially. This is almost always because of automatic type co-ercion. You've already noticed where `0` evaluates to `false`. So if PHP has a reason to convert `'0'` to an integer, then that will also evaluate to false. The prime one to watch out for is the `empty()` function. This is documented, BTW.

I rarely use `empty()` because of this very problem, in fact. It makes much more sense to check more narrowly, hence I use `isset()`, `is_null()` and `=== false` or even `== 0` (or `!= 0`). There are other checks, too. I have DB handler code that not only checks using `is_null()` but also does `is_numeric()`.

Other places to watch out for are where you use other developer's code who aren't completely careful with how `0` works in automatic type co-ercion. If you give a function a `0` but it ends up using a `null` when it should be using a `0` then you've probably found a bug in the API and should raise it with the developer. In fact, they're probably using `empty()` when they should be using `isset()` and/or `is_null()`. :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you want PHP to evaluate a statement with 'false' being the only 'false', use === instead of the usual ==

Answer (score 2):

PHP does allow you to cast variables to a certain type.

```
<?php

   $value = (bool) 0; 
   $value3 = (int) 3; 

?>
```

If you always want 0 to be treated as a int, cast it as one.

Answer (score 1):

None. 0 is 0, even if logical evaluations consider it a false value, that doesn't change its *actual* value.

Comment: In the code example I gave earlier, if I use `$this->db->set('active',0);` and then I try to insert that record in the db, the value of the record is actually null. However if I change it to `$this->db->set('active','0');` so 0 is in single quotes, then 0 is added successfully

Comment: That sounds far more like an issue with whatever DB library you're using, not with PHP.

Comment: The db library simply puts the variable in the query, like this: `"UPDATE .. SET active='$active'";`

Answer (score 1):

I can't find of a single case where PHP would convert `0` to `null` or `""`. If it has to convert it to a string, it will be `"0"`, to a boolean it will be `false`. There's no "null" type, so really your `0` is safe with PHP. `false` is converted to `""` (an empty string) when cast as a string, but integers are safe.

Now it's not a guarantee that third-party code won't behave strangely when passed an integer when they expected something else, but you're mostly safe.

Comment: In PHP, null is a special type that has one valid value: null itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a variable to 0, the variable remains as 0 unless you cast it to something else. The type is still integer.

You can check whether a variable is  by using the [is_numeric](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)() function.

Example:

```
$active=(isActive()) ? 1 : 0;
if(is_numeric($active)){
     $this->db->set('isActive',$active);
}
```

Or You can use the comparison operator === instead of the usual ==. it'll compare the data type as well as the content of the variable.

```
$active=(isActive()) ? 1 : 0;
if($active === 0 || $active === 1){
     $this->db->set('isActive',$active);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Using the === comparison operator is best as it checks that the types are equal as well as their values. In php if you do:

Your best bet is to use true and false where you can, rather than setting 1 and 0 for flags. In your example, do:

```
$active=(isActive()) ? true : false;
```

or even better (assuming isActive returns a proper boolean):

```
$this->db->set('isActive',isActive());
```

rather than:

```
$active=(isActive()) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: In MySQL, bool is actually a column of INT(1), which stores either 0 or 1. Hence your method will not work at all. I need to pass on 0 and 1 exactly